# Alternative to display none to take content out of the viewport

Tags: html, css, viewport

I am building an inline tabbed interface, and I need to show/hide elements based on user interaction. However I can't simply use the css `display none` property to hide an element, because it breaks other scripts that rely on the element's css properties such as its sze.

Is there a bulletproof alternative that would allow me to take an element offscreen?

I have found a number of suggestions on the Web, but all of them have shortcomings:

`position:absolute;top:-9999px`: will force the page to scroll back to the top.

`position:absolute;left:-9999px`: will create a scrollbar in right to left pages. Also, it seems to require more processing time because the browser actually builds a much bigger page.

`clip(1px,1px,1px,1px)`: will resize the element to 1 pixel, which is too big for my case (especially as I am hiding a dozen elements).

Comment: opposed to visibilty hidden which will keep area where element is and not display the text/content contained by element , you could use on of the position with overflow hidden to negate a scroller

Answer (score 2):

What if you try remove element from the stream and then hide it?

```
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
```

Comment: Same comment as for @laaposto's answer, it seems that the browser still uses the invisible elements to determine the scroll height.

Comment: @Christophe Can i see example? 
Try to add "bottom: 0; right: 0;". http://jsfiddle.net/iamsashka/3Jf8M/

Comment: +1 this looks promising after adding bottom 0. I'll need to do more cross-browser testing, as I didn't find this option detailed anywhere.

Comment: I did some more testing, and this has the same issue as the `left:-9999px` technique: it will create a scrollbar for right to left content. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3Jf8M/1/

Comment: @Christophe It's voodoo: you must change properties (top, right, bottom, left) to opposite depending of the text direction and if you use negative value.
But you can add "overflow: hidden;" to parent element.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this css rule to the elements you dont want to show

```
position: absolute;
visibility:hidden
```

The elements are invisible and out of the flow

Comment: As you say, the element will still take up space, so this won't work for my tabbed interface.

Comment: @Christophe, try using this style with `position: absolute;` as well. This way, it gets taken out of the flow of the document, so that it won't affect the positioning of other elements, but will still retain it's size.

Comment: @Christophe as @Blake Mann says you have to use it with `position:absolute;`

Comment: ok, let me try that. I wonder if there is any downside, as I have never seen this option before.

Comment: I tried this technique, and I am having an issue with vertical scrollbars. I am not sure why, but my assumption is that the browser still uses the invisible elements to determine the scroll height.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution that seems to be used in a couple frameworks:

```
border:0;
clip:rect(0 0 0 0);
height:1px;
margin:-1px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0;
position:absolute;
width:1px;
```

The height and width ensure that the content will be read by screen readers. margin -1 offsets these dimensions to give the element an actual size of 0.